# I am not able to click on the text

Tags: android, appium

I have tried to click on 'WOMEN' but I don't know why it doesn't clicking on it.
I am using `java-client 5.0.4`, `appium 1.8.1`, and `jdk1.8`

Can anybody help me?

My code is below.

`driver.findElementByXPath(("//android.widget.TextView[@text='WOMEN']")).click();`

[image]

Log is here

```
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/03f470f3-6c91-496c-a072-9c2ff1fb0b66/element
[HTTP] {"using":"xpath","value":"//android.widget.TextView[@text='WOMEN']"}
[W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: ["xpath","//android.widget.TextView[@text='WOMEN']","03f470f3-6c91-496c-a072-9c2ff1fb0b66"]
[BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
[BaseDriver] Waiting up to 0 ms for condition
[AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//android.widget.TextView[@text='WOMEN']","context":"","multiple":false}}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//android.widget.TextView[@text='WOMEN']","context":"","multiple":false}}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding '//android.widget.TextView[@text='WOMEN']' using 'XPATH' with the contextId: '' multiple: false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use more reliable way using `resource-id` with below Mentioned Command

```
driver.findElement(By.id("complete text in resource-id")).click();
```

Comment: just check once if element is found or not using above command
syso(driver.findElements(By.id("complete text in resource-id")).size());

There may be other issues like 
1. waits are not properly implemented
2. Your app is under webview.

Comment: [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding 'com.rarewire.xxx:id/tv_onboard_category_title' using 'ID' with the contextId: '' multiple: false
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.rarewire.xxx:id/tv_onboard_category_title]
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":7,"value":"No element found"}
[AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[MJSONWP] Matched JSONWP error code 7 to NoSuchElementError
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/d1c4f090-02e5-4953-9b1c-f7d9e92e87e8/element 500 7167

Comment: I tried many things like implicitlyWait before click it. but element is not found.

Comment: Can you try below code if it is showing webview in your app
Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
for (String contextName : contextNames) {
    System.out.println(contextNames); //prints out something like NATIVE_APP \n WEBVIEW_1
}
Show the output for this

Comment: It said [NATIVE_APP]     Is it related with type of debug apk or release apk?

Comment: IF you are able to see anything like this android.webkit.WebView in your app it means you have to get androidwebview debugger to be enabled
i.e. this should be added to your build by dev team WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);

Comment: Thank you Amit bhai.but it's not included webview.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the `xpath` using appium application which shows whole `xpath` it will be easy for you

java - > `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@content-desc=\"testEmail\"]")).click();`

Comment: Thank you Al lmran. I know how to do xpath. but it's not working. Also, As you can see there is no content-desc.

Comment: I think App is hybrid Content-desc attribute need to be added by programmer.

Comment: well...They said it's native app not hybrid.

Comment: Man can you post xpath , to find xpath it doesnt needed content-desc.

Comment: Can you post appium server log.

Comment: sure. 
[debug] �[35m[AndroidBootstrap]�[39m [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding 'com.rarewire.test:id/tv_onboard_change[@text='CHANGE']' using 'XPATH' with the contextId: '' multiple: false[debug] �[35m[AndroidBootstrap]�[39m [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Failed to locate element. Clearing Accessibility cache and retrying.

Comment: [debug] �[35m[AndroidBootstrap]�[39m [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding 'com.rarewire.test:id/tv_onboard_change[@text='CHANGE']' using 'XPATH' with the contextId: '' multiple: false[debug] �[35m[AndroidBootstrap]�[39m [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":7,"value":"No element found"}
[debug] �[35m[AndroidBootstrap]�[39m Received command result from bootstrap
[debug] �[35m[MJSONWP]�[39m Matched JSONWP error code 7 to NoSuchElementError

Comment: [info] �[35m[HTTP]�[39m �[37m<-- POST /wd/hub/session/c825e391-4bc9-4b47-bce9-b782529d4ba2/element �[39m�[31m500�[39m �[90m1014 ms - 164�[39m
[info] �[35m[HTTP]�[39m �[90m�[39m

Comment: Which application you are using to find xpath

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176377/discussion-between-aravithapa-and-everline).

Comment: I use uiautomatorviewer 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize your driver and capabilities life following:

```
AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver;   
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Android phone");
caps.setCapability("udid", "your device id");
caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "phone version");
caps.setCapability("appPackage", appPackage);
caps.setCapability("appActivity", appActivity);
driver=new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL(
        "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
```

if you have initialize your desired capabilities and driver like above you must be able to use:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("your resource id")).click();
```

or try to print

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("your resource id")).getText());
```

Comment: Hi, Android doesn't have UDID. I tried it except UDID. but it doesn't work.

Comment: Android its its own Unique Device ID. To find out your device uuid, connect your device to the computer. Make sure you have enabled usb debugging mode from developer option. Type adb devices in command prompt. It will show list of devices connected to computer. There you can find your device udid. Its pattern is like **ED1DU16616002292**

Comment: Were you able to lunch your app with your driver and desired capability initialization?

Comment: Of course. To make sure, another apk file works fine to testing like touch, drag and drop click and so on. but only this apk file doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's in python, but you can apply it to Java:

```
recovery_text = 'Forgot your password?'
recovery_psw = self.driver.instance.find_element_by_android_uiautomator('new UiSelector().text("' + recovery_text + '")')
recovery_psw.click()
```